# "exhaustMap" in Project Reactor?

Tags: project-reactor

Is there an equivalent operator in Reactor for exhaustMap from RxJs (https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap)?

> A function that returns an Observable containing projected Observables of each item of the source, ignoring projected Observables that start before their preceding Observable has completed.

I found switchMap, flatMap/mergeMap, concatMap but there is no exhaustMap operator in Reactor as far as I have seen. Is there an other way to replicate the exhaustMap in Reactor?

Comment: Please provide a short description (and additionnally link to related api doc) of RxJS `exhaustMap` function. It wil add context to your question, ithout requiring readers to search what is that RxJs function themself.

Comment: From what I understand from [RxJs exhaustMap function](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/exhaustMap), it sequentially (one by one) flatMap values from a source observable. For me, its equivalent is [Flux.concatMap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: concatMap does not ignore projected Observables that start before the preceding Observable has completed.

Comment: So exhaustMap is a sort of [conflation](https://docs.diffusiondata.com/docs/latest/manual/html/designguide/data/conflation/conflationtypes.html). It looks more applicable to hot flows than to cold ones. Do you have a code sample showing your use-case ?